# Change Compositing Nodes for all Scenes

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is it possible to use one Compositing "Configuration" for all Scenes?
I have about 40 Scenes in my current Project and need to make a few not-so-small changes to the compositing. It's the same for all scenes.

Is that possible? Maybe via a script?

Using Blender 3.6 (with Octane)

Comment: via script for sure. I don't know other ways...maybe an add-on.